# How can I create an array in AsyncStorage?

Tags: react-native

I want to create a shopping cart. I use this code to save some data like `username`. Now I want to save product `ID` and `Count` in an array in `AsyncStorage`. 
(I use expo.)

How can I do that?

```
  _save_user = async () => {
  await SecureStore.setItemAsync('username', parseInt(this.state.Username).toString());
  };
```

Please tell me if you have some better idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
var item1 = {itemCode:"10101010", quantity:"500", anythingElse:"this"};
var item2 = {itemCode:"10102020", quantity:"42", anythingElse:"is"};
var item3 = {itemCode:"10103030", quantity:"2", anythingElse:"something"};
var yourArray = [item1,item2,item3];

  _save_array = async () => {
     await SecureStore.setItemAsync('yourKey', JSON.stringify(yourArray));
  };
```

Comment: This way is not good. How can I save count of a product? And after that I want to show product and count in one page like cart page. How can I get that array? encode data to json is so good, but how can I save data like this: [username]=>{[productName]=> "Samsung" , [count]=> "5", [sum]=> "25800"}

Comment: @AlirezaDarvishi I just modify it, you can acces that object normally like 
yourArray[<ItemPosition>].itemCode / yourArray[<ItemPosition>].quantity / yourArray[<ItemPosition>].anythingElse
```